# Two-Way Data Binding With Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

So Meteor uses `getMeteorData()` instead of `getInitialState()` so how do we do binding? Considering this user profile's surname:

```
...

getMeteorData() {
 return {
   u = Meteor.user()
 }
},

componentRender() {
  let instance = this;
  // there is no way you can have two-way binding here. She types in "Brown".
  return(<div><input value={instance.data.user.profile.surname }</div>)
},

render() {
 return(<div>{this.data.user ?  this.componentRender() : <p>Loading...</p>}</div>)
}

...
```

How do you write an `onChange` function for this? I only know the `setState`'s way of doing things. Also that code is a one-way binding as if "Sue" wants to change her last name, "Brown" will not be replaced.

[Two-way binding with React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) includes the `getInitialState` function.

**Update:**

I have solved my answer with my [medium post](http://goo.gl/uC8fYb).

Answer (score 2):

Meteor does not give you auto two way binding by default.

You will need to add a on change event handler for your input to handle updates in the user name.

In your onChanged, you can make a call to update the user's surname.

```
Meteor.users.update ...
```

Please not that this is not efficient at all as an update is called every time user changed the input. It is better to have a button to click on to trigger the update event.

See: [Meteor React Docs on updates](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/update-and-remove)

Comment: Yes but there is more to that. I already have the `Meteor.users.update` in place. I want binding of the input field. Because `value` is set, when you try to type it wont change. Just try for yourself and see. My only work around  which answers my question is this: http://goo.gl/uC8fYb